# GTMNSString+HTML functions not working after integrating Google vision api in iOS

Tags: ios

I am working on iOS. I was using this GTMNSString+HTML.h / GTMNSString+HTML.m file for removing html tags from string, but after integration of mobilevision framework the function `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML` is not being called.

By putting a breakpoint inside `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML` and debugging, it just does not go inside the `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML function`

Frameworks added are:

- BarcodeDetector.framework
- GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
- GoogleMobileVision.framework
- GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
- GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
- GoogleUtilities.framework

If I rename `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML` to anything other such as `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML`, then it starts working.

What should I do to use functions `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML` without renaming-- or is renaming the only option, and if so then why?